# Looking for a pay or free scroller NOT wordpress

Tags: gallery, scroller

Looking for a pay or free horizontal scroller that has picture enlarening.  Basically pics scrolling by and when you click on one it gets full size.  I cannot find one anywhere.  I also want it to only be one image high.  any help would be appriciated.  I will gladly pay for one!  NOT WORDPRESS

google search 10 pages deep.  NOT WORDPRESS

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.